# Capitalising Abbreviations in Titles

Tags: capitalization

Could you, please, tell me whether it is mandatory to capitalise lowercase abbreviations in titles (*e.g., viz., vs., i.e.*), or it's completely wrong, or it's just a matter of preference?

1. **Kittens *vs.* Puppies**

1.2. **Kittens *Vs.* Puppies**

2. **Aminals, People, *etc.* And, of Course, Mushrooms**

2.2. **Animals, People, *Etc.* And, of Course, Mushrooms**

Comment: *versus*  (*vs.*) is a preposition — lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

It's customary that "short words" - specifically conjunctions, articles and prepositions - are not capitalized in titles (except at the start of the title). I would treat "vs." as a kind of preposition. In any case I would also always leave words like that lowercase. Anything else looks weird. So:

> *Kittens vs. Puppies*

In your second example "and" is one of the words not usually capitalized. It's also weird in other ways - for example you would not normally have another item in a list after "etc." - "Etc." means "and so on" and thus would include all the things you would normally expect to be in the list which would (of course) include mushrooms. You might try:

> Animals, People and, of Course, Mushrooms etc.

It doesn't mean exactly the same thing, but if it covers what you want I would use it. The whole thing is a weird title, and if you are not deliberately looking
to create a weird title write it another way.   Alternatively:

> Of Course Mushrooms, and Animals, People etc.

I'm in two minds about the capitalization of "of" and "course". I also think that if you spelled out "etcetera" in full I would probably capitalize it, but not "versus"

Comment: *I'm in two minds about the capitalization of "of" and "course".* Indeed, in both your last two suggestions the capitalisation of *Course* rather suggests it is of equal status to *Animals, People, Mushrooms* and I'm not sure that capitalising *Of* too would fix that problem.

Comment: Of course and etc. are not usually in titles. Otherwise I agree.